# Android Webview select a word by tapping on it.

Tags: android, webview, selection

I am using webview in one of my android projects(OS version 4.4+). Webview gives default functionality to select the text by "longpressing". But my project requirement is to select the text just by tapping on it and not by long pressing. I have tried methods mentioned in this link to achieve the functionality ([Detect which word has been clicked on within a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563169/detect-which-word-has-been-clicked-on-within-a-text)). But it is not working for me. Can any one please guide how to achieve this task.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034369/how-to-select-a-word-in-android-webview

Comment: please provide the exact code you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: this is the code <jsfiddle.net/Vap7C/15/> i tried. it is working fine in mozilla browswer but not on android tablet. It return empty string

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi the link you mentioned says that you cannot achieve it. can you suggest some word arounds

Comment: yes this right it is impossible. also refer another link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076113/android-highlight-a-word-phrase-in-a-webview

Comment: you can do one thing get data from server in string and show it in textview then select it.

Answer (score 1):

By this below method, you can select text by clicking on it after 1 second without needing to hold it:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        Boolean tF;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            tF = true;
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    tF = false;
            }
            return tF;
        }
});
```